# vs2013 compile for debug but not for release?

Tags: qt, visual-c++

I have met strange things in VS2013.
My program builds well in debug mode.
But in release mode, there are many errors like:

```
 Error 2 error C2440: 'default argument' : cannot convert from 'const wchar_t [1]' to 'const BSTR'   (src\GAudioOutput.cc) C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\sapi.h 16917 1 qgroundcontrol
```

This is the newest version of vs 2013 express version. I just got it yesterday.
Is this a vs2013's bug?
Any solutions?
EDIT: All the errors are C2440: cannot convert from xxx to xxx

EDIT2: The same code I compiled without any problem using VS2010. And I found that all the errors are from the windows_kit 8.1. Any thoughts?

Comment: Compare the build settings for debug and release. Probably you are compiling one as Unicode and the other as ascii.

Comment: Probably you added some preprocessor directives to the debug version and not to the release version. I would start by comparing the project settings of the two versions.

Comment: Sorry, but where to check?

Comment: ***Sorry, but where to check?*** Character Set which is in the General tab of configuration properties for your project.

Comment: They are the same...

Comment: @WernerHenze The ASCII configuration doesn't solve the incompatibility between BSTR (UNICODE-independent) and `const wchar_t[1]' (can't be issued by ASCII).

Comment: Show more code:  The prototype of the function and the definition of the parameter that you pass. If it isn't a function call but an assigenment, than show the left and right side of the assignment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same compile error when building a project with Qt5.4 and msvc2013. It is because the windows headers violate the standard, and it will be fixed by adding the following line in the .pro file:

```
win32: QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE -= -Zc:strictStrings
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out the reason:

I am using the newest Qt 5.4 beta. And there's a bug in Qt 5.4 beta causing the resulted project in VS2013's release build to stop working.

Though it might not be that helpful to other people, those using windows and vs 2013, please avoid using qt 5.4 beta version.

Comment: This is just a generic comment about beta software - If you're using beta software, coming to a public user group to get help will be counterproductive.  Instead, it would see that the support site for that beta would be the locale most helpful for support.

Answer (score 1):

By adding this line to .pro file

```
win32: QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE -= -Zc:strictStrings
```

You still get the error when your code include a external .h file which violated strictStrings rules.

A better way is to delete -Zc:strictStrings from entries 
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE and QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE_WITH_DEBUGINFO in file $QT_DIR/mkspecs/win32-msvc2013/qmake.conf